# How to connect database which is on aws VM from azure website

Tags: sql-server, azure, amazon-web-services

I want to connect to the database which is on Amazon AWS VM from azure website.
It is giving error "not accessible" 
Any configuration I have to made in AWS VM

Answer (score 2):

You need to setup a security group and open up inbound and outbound ports in AWS.
Only after your sql server port is opened you can connect to your sserver from Azure.
If you are using MySql which uses 3306 port by default (you need to change this for security reasons), you need to open up 3306 to recieve and throw bytes.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your network firewall settings in both azure and aws? I suspect that's your issue. Create exceptions for the proper IP addresses.